# Stencil inside Stencil? (Multiple masks on same object)

Tags: unity, masking, stencil

So please take a look at what I want to achieve
[image: Multiple Masks]

The Red and Blue part is the object I want to mask. The thing is that it will be masked by the green area, and only after that it will be masked by the cyan area, which shall act like a scrollview. Currently I use stencil shader and the first mask works, but I don't know how to apply the second mask. Also, I don't want to use the built-in UI mask system for this. All the objects in the scene are sprites.

The thing is that I would like to achieve a hierarchy masking system, where the kids are masked by a parent.

Could you please give me a tip about what I should do in this case?